# Socket programming Update: recv returning -1, error = 10053

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, tcp, recv

I'm implementing a TCP/IP application on Windows 7 that loops around a socket recv() call. For small amount of data (< 5 MB) it works fine, but for large data (>20 MB), the recv fails in between.

**Details:** My app needs to communicate with HTTP server running , both running on same machine, in this scenerio, tcp app is sending heavy data to HTTP server

It gives error = 2, recv returns 0.

**Error 2 means ENOENT, but what does it means?**. Does anyone know what this is (in regards to a socket) and how I can get around this?

```
msgLen = recv(s,msg,BUFFER_SIZE,0);

if(msgLen > 0)
{
  // do processing
}
else
{
  printf("\n no data received .... msgLen=%d",msgLen);
  printf("\n no data received .... errno=%d",errno);
}
```

**Update Code as per comment**

```
msgLen = recv(s,msg,BUFFER_SIZE,0);

if(msgLen > 0)
{
  // do processing
}
else if(msgLen == 0)
{
  printf("\n sender disconnected");
}
else
{
  printf("\n no data received .... msgLen=%d",msgLen);
  printf("\n no data received .... errno=%d",WSAGetLastError());
}
```

The error I get now is:

1. Firstly, recv = 0 many times, i.e. sender disconnected;
2. Finally, recv returns -1, and error = 10053.

My TCP/IP application is sending data to HTTP Server. The same works fine with small data, but the issue comes with large amount of data. Is HTTP server getting time out?

Comment: Are you using WSAGetLastError() to get the error code? Windows doesn't use 'errno'.

Comment: @roger_rowland ok, i would check with WSAGetLastError() and update soon.

Comment: @Rohit *Why* are you getting `recv()` returning zero many times? You should have closed the socket and stopped reading the *first* time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `recv()` returns 0, it means the other party disconnected gracefully (assuming that your requested buffer size is not 0).  `recv()` only provides an error code when it returns `SOCKET_ERROR` (-1).  On Windows, you have to use `WSAGetLastError()` to get the error code, not `errno`, eg:

```
msgLen = recv(s,msg,BUFFER_SIZE,0);

if(msgLen > 0)
{
    // do processing
}
else if (msgLen == 0)
{
    printf("\n sender disconnected");
}
else
{
    printf("\n no data received .... error=%d",WSAGetLastError());
}
```

Also keep in mind that if you are using a non-blocking socket, the error code may be `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`, which is not a fatal error.  You can use `select()` to detect when the socket has data and then attempt the `recv()` again.

Comment: The error i get now is

Firstly recv=0 many times, i.e. sender disconnected

Finally recv returns -1, and error = 10053

Comment: 10053 is `WSAECONNABORTED`. When `recv()` returns 0, **the connection is already gone**, so stop using it. Call `closesocket()`on it to clean up resources and move on.